# search the "local minimum" in martix

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, arr

> Matrix element is called the local minimum if it is strictly less than its neighbors. Calculate the minimum amount specified matrix.

I dont know how to do this((

this is my code:

```
include <iostream>
include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void main() {
    const int row = 3, col = 4;
    int arr[row][col], count = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            if ((arr[i][j] < arr[i][j + 1]) && 
                (arr[i][j] < arr[i + 1][j]) && 
                (arr[i][j] < arr[i + 1][j + 1])) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << endl << count << endl;
}
```

Now I need to determine the extreme elements (because with not extreme - work)

Comment: you need to remove the semicolon from your if statement. Also, if you are looking for your local minimum, shouldn't you be searching in both directions, and not just forward (ie -1 instead of just +1). And finally, for the extreme, this is your basic algor

Comment: Another problem is that `[i + 1]` and `[j + 1]` will be out of range for max values of `i` and `j`.

Comment: Also, whenever you use **arr[i][j+1] or arr[i+1][j], please remember to check the array index out of bounds condition**.

Comment: @User_Targaryen how I must do this?

Comment: And finally, for your extreme min/max, look up std::min, std::max. Hint: you need to store a value which tracks the extreme max and extreme min, and compare it as you iterate

Comment: @tkachuk - When comparing an element with the next one, you have to consider that some elements doesn't *have*  a next element. Like the last one on each row or column.

Answer (score 0):

you have an `if` that tests nothing because of the semicolon

So `count` is updated everytime.

```
     if 
           ((arr[i][j] < arr[i][j + 1]) && 
           (arr[i][j] < arr[i + 1][j]) && 
           (arr[i][j] < arr[i + 1][j + 1])); // <= remove the semicolon
                count++;
```